# How to include CSS file in the XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

So I have a CSS file like below

```
.table_class1DeffCell
{
border-top-width : 1;
border-left-width : 1;
border-right-width : 1;
border-bottom-width : 1;
}
.table_class11DeffCell
{
border-bottom-color : 000000;
border-top-color : 000000;
border-right-color : 000000;
border-left-color : 000000;
border-top-style : solid;
border-left-style : solid;
border-right-style : solid;
border-bottom-style : solid;
border-top-width : 1;
border-left-width : 1;
border-right-width : 1;
border-bottom-width : 1;
}
.table_class24DeffCell
{
border-bottom-color : 000000;
border-top-color : 000000;
border-right-color : 000000;
border-left-color : 000000;
border-top-style : solid;
border-left-style : solid;
border-right-style : solid;
border-bottom-style : solid;
border-top-width : 1;
border-left-width : 1;
border-right-width : 1;
border-bottom-width : 1;
}

.text_class40
{
font-style : italic;
}

.text_class41
{
font-weight : bold;
}

.image_class42
{
}
```

And in the HTML it was linked like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FormatingProblem.css"></link>
```

in the HTML BOLD and Italics works correctly because of linking the CSS file.

Actually I am converting HTML file to Word document, in the case i cant do these BOLD and Italics.

this is my XSLT file

```
 <table width="100%">
            <tr>
              <xsl:if test="@class=$TableClass">
                <!--left Table Cell-->
                <xsl:choose>
                  <!--Requirement-->
                  <xsl:when test="td[@class=$RequirementType]/span/span/. = 'Non Functional' or td[@class=$RequirementType]/span/span/. = 'Functional' or td[@class=$RequirementType]/span/span/. = 'Scenario' or td[@class=$RequirementType]/span/span/. = 'Actor'">
                    <td style="border-Top: black 1.0pt solid; border-Bottom: #4896a black 1.0pt solid; vertical-align:'top'" bgcolor = "#DDD9C3" width="80%">
                      <!--Text-->
                      <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Requirements">
                        <xsl:for-each select="td[@class=$Requirements]/span/span | td[@class=$Requirements]/span/br | td[@class=$Requirements]/span/blockquote">
                          <span>
                            <xsl:if test="name() != 'br'">
                              <xsl:value-of select="." />
                              <xsl:if test="name() = 'blockquote'">
                                <br/>
                              </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="name() = 'br'">
                              <br/>
                            </xsl:if>

                          </span>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <br />
                      <br />
                      <!--Reference-->
                      <xsl:if test="td/@class=$References">
                        <xsl:if test="string-length(td[@class=$References]/span/span)!=0">
                          <span>
                            <br />
                            <xsl:for-each select="td[@class=$References]/span/span | td[@class=$References]/span/br">
                              <span>
                                <xsl:if test="name() != 'br'">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="name() = 'br'">
                                  <br/>
                                </xsl:if>
                              </span>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                          </span>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <br />
                      <br />
                    </td>
                  </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <!--right Table Cell-->
                <xsl:choose>
                  <!--Requirement-->
                  <xsl:when test="td[@class=$RequirementType]/span/span/. = 'Functional' or td[@class=$RequirementType]/span/span/. = 'Non Functional' or td[@class=$RequirementType]/span/span/. = 'Scenario' or td[@class=$RequirementType]/span/span/. = 'Actor'">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <!--Search 1-->
                      <xsl:when test="td[@class=$Auxiliary]/span[contains(span, $search1)]">
                        <td style="vertical-align:'top'" bgcolor="{$search1Color}" width="20%">
                          <span style="font-size:8pt">
                            <!--UID_ATR-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$UID">
                              ID:
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$UID]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_ID-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$TFS_ID">
                              TFS:
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$TFS_ID]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Triage-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Triage">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Triage]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--V. In-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$V.In">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$V.In]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Priority-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Priority">
                              (Prio
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Priority]/." />)
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Requirement Type-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$RequirementType">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$RequirementType]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <!--Auxiliary-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Auxiliary">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Auxiliary]/." />
                              <br />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <!--Search 2-->
                      <xsl:when test="td[@class=$Auxiliary]/span[contains(span, $search2)]">
                        <td style="vertical-align:'top'" bgcolor="{$search2Color}" width="20%">
                          <span style="font-size:8pt">
                            <!--UID_ATR-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$UID">
                              ID:
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$UID]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_ID-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$TFS_ID">
                              TFS:
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$TFS_ID]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Triage-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Triage">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Triage]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--V. In-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$V.In">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$V.In]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Priority-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Priority">
                              (Prio
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Priority]/." />)
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Requirement Type-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$RequirementType">
                              <!--Zeilenumbruch-->
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$RequirementType]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <!--Auxiliary-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Auxiliary">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Auxiliary]/." />
                              <br />
                              <!--Zeilenumbruch-->
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <!--No Search-->
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td style="vertical-align:'top'" width="20%">
                          <span style="font-size:8pt">
                            <!--UID_ATR-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$UID">
                              ID:
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$UID]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_ID-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$TFS_ID">
                              TFS:
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$TFS_ID]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Triage-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Triage">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Triage]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--V. In-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$V.In">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$V.In]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Priority-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Priority">
                              (Prio
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Priority]/." />)
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <!--TFS_Requirement Type-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$RequirementType">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$RequirementType]/." />
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <!--Auxiliary-->
                            <xsl:if test="td/@class=$Auxiliary">
                              <xsl:value-of select="td[@class=$Auxiliary]/." />
                              <br />
                              <!--Zeilenumbruch-->
                            </xsl:if>
                            <br />
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <!--No Requirement-->
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <span width="20%"></span>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:if>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

in the HTML, Its show like below image

[image]

And After converting to Word format, **BOLD**(Character) Will not Work like below image

[image]

What I wrong in this?

Comment: You can link a CSS file to an XML file using `<?xml-stylesheet ...?>`. If you are using the XSLT to generate a new HTML on the fly, you can add the same `<link>` element to the result tree so the resulting HTML refers to it. Which file are you converting to Word? The resulting XML? You can also convert the HTML directly into a docx word document.

Comment: I have tried like <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('/FormatingProblem.css')"/>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FormatingProblem.css" />-->
      </head>
</html>

Comment: This question makes no sense. XSLT has no "bold". XSLT is for transforming XML to (for example) HTML.  Simply include the link to the CSS in the HTML you produce.

Comment: I think what you are asking is that you are actually converting an HTML document to a Word document using XSLT. And that you want elements that are styled bold (using the CSS) in the HTML to be styled bold in the Word document. This is not a trivial task, I am afraid!

Comment: @TimC : Yes I am Converting an HTML to Word and PDF Document Using XSLT, I know in the XSLT file we can use <b> to BOLD the body text. is any possible to BOLD/Italics XSLT file using these CSS file?

Comment: XSLT does not have a concept of "bold". It can, however, output code which other programs (like Word) recognise as bold. So, you first need to find out how bold text is done in Word, so you know what to output. If you are trying to read the CSS file in XSLT though to find out which elements need to be made bold in Word, then this is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: @TimC : ok, then Can you suggest any article or how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the problem is.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FormatingProblem.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes I tried like this but I got this error  Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited

Comment: So I used this code XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
    settings.EnableScript = true;
    myXslTrans.Load(_xsltPath, settings, null);       But i got the same error.

Comment: My answer does not use the `document()` function.

Comment: ok, but BOLD and italics are not working, these both .text_class40 and .text_class41 is linked to HTML file, but in the XSLT its not working Why?

Comment: @VikramBose Perhaps you could be a _little_ more specific than "not working"? _What_ is not working, and in what way? Which XMl document are you transforming in the first place, and where is your XSLT code? And how is this related to generating a Word document? Do not answer those questions here in the comment section - edit your question.